# Regular local ring if every maximal Cohen-Macaulay module is free

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, cohen-macaulay, regular-rings

I have a problem like this

"Let $R$ be a Cohen-Macaulay local ring, $\dim R=d$. Given that every maximal Cohen-Macaulay $R$-module is free, prove that $R$ is a regular local ring."

My lecturer gave me a hint to use the Auslander-Buchsbaum theorem: $\operatorname{depth} R=\operatorname{depth}_R M +\operatorname{pd}_R M$ if $\operatorname{pd}_R M<\infty$. However, I am still stuck since I want to prove that $\operatorname{pd}_R R/\mathfrak{m}<\infty$, but I don't know how the hint works at all?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It is enough to prove that every finitely generated module has finite projective dimension. If $M$ is a finitely generated module and not free, then by assumption $\mathrm{depth}\, M<\mathrm{depth} \,R$. Let $0\to N\to R^n\to M\to 0$ be exact. Can you say $\mathrm{depth} \,N>\mathrm{depth} \, M$ and finish the rest of the proof?

Comment: @long, please add a complete answer!

Comment: @LongLêThiên One can prove that the $d$th syzygy of every finitely generated $R$-module ($R$ local CM of dimension $d$, of course) is or zero or a MCM. (See Bruns and Herzog, Exercise 2.1.26 or [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159390/bruns-herzog-problem-2-1-26-page-64).) This solves the problem immediately.